# I want to open a Text file in Gedit, using python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I am just working on linux and using python tkinter and want to open a text file in gedit rather than opening it in cli.

Comment: And what is the issue then?

Comment: You can use `subprocess.Popen()`: `subprocess.Popen(['gedit', '/path/to/the/text/file'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/webbrowser.html#module-webbrowser):

```py
import webbrowser

def open_file(file_name):
    webbrowser.open(file_name)
```

This should open the said file in your default text editor (like notepad in windows or gedit in linux). You can add a button in your GUI and call a function that runs the above code.